# What does .nonzero()[0] mean when we want to compute the sparsity of a matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I am trying to learn about recommender systems in Python by reading a blog that contains a great example of creating a recommender system of repositories in GitHub.

Once the dataset is loaded with read_csv(), the person that wrote the code decided to convert that data into a pivot_table pandas for visualizing the data in a more simple way. Here, I left you an image of that part of the code for simplicity:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFtRk.png)

In that table, rows are the users and columns are the repositories. The cross section between a row and a column is the punctuation that a user gives to a particular repository.

Due to the fact that many of the elements of that table are null (we can say that we are having a sparse matrix, very typical in machine learning), he decided to study the level of sparsity of the matrix by means of this code:

```
ratings = df_matrix.values
sparsity = float(len(ratings.nonzero()[0]))
sparsity /= (ratings.shape[0] * ratings.shape[1])
sparsity *= 100
print('Sparsity: {:4.2f}%'.format(sparsity))
```

Could anyone help me to know what the second line of code means?
I think I understand that ratings.nonzero() returns a list with the indexes of all the elements that are different from zero and, as I interested in the total numbers and not the indexes, it is necessary to use len(ratings.nonzero()), but my problem is that it is impossible to me to know what the [0] means in the code.

Thank you very much and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `nonzero` will return a tuple of the form `(row_idxs, col_idxs)`. If you hand it a one-dimensional array (like a pandas series), then it will still return a tuple, `(row_idxs,)`. To access this first array, we still must index `ratings.nonzero()[0]` to get the first-dimension index of nonzero elements.

More info available on the numpy page for `nonzero` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), as both pandas and numpy use the same implementation.